# Generate database with Nhibernate using Fluent NHibernate

Tags: database, nhibernate, configuration, fluent-nhibernate

I'm trying to use (new with) Fluent NHibernate (trying to switch from XML mapping file to FNH). With the code below, I generated the database, I'm trying to find the same solution but with FNH (I'd like still use hibernate.cfg.xml) :

```
public void CreateDatabase()
{
    NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration cfg = new NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration();

    cfg.Configure();
    SchemaMetadataUpdater.QuoteTableAndColumns(cfg);
    NHibernate.Tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport schema = new NHibernate.Tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport(cfg);

    schema.Create(false, true);
}


namespace MyTestApplication.Entities
{
    public class Person
    {
        public virtual int Id { get; set; }
        public virtual string FirstName { get; set; }
        public virtual string LastName { get; set; }
    }
}

namespace MyTestApplication.Data.Mapping
{
    public class PersonMapping : ClassMap<Person>
    {
        public PersonMapping()
        {
            Id(x => x.Id);
            Map(x => x.FirstName);
            Map(x => x.LastName);      
        }
    }
}
```

**Solution**

Finally, I use this (Thanks to Marco) :

```
 public void CreationDB()
    {
        FluentConfiguration config = Fluently.Configure()
            .Database(MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2008.ConnectionString("......"))
            .Mappings(
                m => m.FluentMappings.Add(typeof(MyTestApplication.Data.Mapping.PersonMapping)
            ));

        config.ExposeConfiguration(
                  c => new SchemaExport(c).Execute(true, true, false))
             .BuildConfiguration();
    }
```

Comment: Thank you! You made my day and saved me hours of research

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I use this, even if I think you could find something more elegant:

```
public FluentConfiguration GetConfig()
{
    return Fluently.Configure()
        .Database(
              MySQLConfiguration.Standard.ConnectionString(
                    c => c.Server("...").Database("...").Username("...").Password("..."))
        )
        .Mappings(
              m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly())
        );
}

public void Export(bool script, bool export, bool justDrop)
{
    GetConfig()
         .ExposeConfiguration(
              c => new SchemaExport(c).Execute(script, export, justDrop))
         .BuildConfiguration();
}
```

Finally I call `Export(true, true, false)`.